# Autodesk Suite 2013 Batch Install not waiting for completion

Tags: batch-file, wait, autodesk

I'm trying to install the Autodesk2013 Suite using this batch

```
@echo off
title Installing Autodesk Suite then logging off....

NET USE \\directory /user:********\****** ****** /persistent:YES

ECHO "Installing Autodesk Suite. This workstation will log off automatically when installation is complete."

START /WAIT /B "" "....\Setup.exe" /qb /I \AutoDesk2013.ini /language en-us

ECHO "Finished"

TIMEOUT /T 10
SHUTDOWN /l /f
EXIT
```

It initialises the install perfectly fine **but it isn't waiting until it's finished**, instantly moves on. I thought /WAIT was meant to stop that?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: Final working batch:**

```
@echo off
title Installing Autodesk Suite then logging off....

NET USE \\sccm\d$ /user:******\***** ******* /persistent:YES

ECHO "Installing Autodesk Suite. This workstation will log off automatically when installation is complete."

START /B "" "\AdminImage\Setup.exe" /qb /I \AdminImage\AutoDesk2013.ini /language en-us
TIMEOUT /T 10
SETLOCAL

SET TARGET=Setup.exe
@ECHO Started!

:LOOP
ping -5 2 localhost >NUL
FOR /F %%T IN ('tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq %TARGET%"') DO (
  SET FOUND=0
  IF "%%~T"=="%TARGET%" SET FOUND=1
)
IF %FOUND%==1 GOTO :LOOP

ECHO "Finished"

TIMEOUT /T 10
SHUTDOWN /l /f
EXIT
```

Comment: Some installers (`setup.exe`) call `msiexec` to do the work and exit, leaving the work to the system. Are you sure this is not your case?

Comment: Is there a way of finding this out without specifically looking up whether the Autodesk Setup does this?

Comment: Start setup and in task manager look if it keeps open or it closes.

Comment: It's so quick I don't think I can tell. I end up with a TrustedInstall.exe and 2 x Setup.exe in TM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/WAIT` is not a guarantee. AutoDesk products are particularly bad about this. We have to monitor the process list for `setup.exe` to discern whether the install is finished or not.

Something like this demonstrates the idea:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET TARGET=notepad.exe
start notepad
@ECHO Started!

:LOOP
ping -n 2 localhost >NUL
FOR /F %%T IN ('tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq %TARGET%"') DO (
  SET FOUND=0
  IF "%%~T"=="%TARGET%" SET FOUND=1
)
IF %FOUND%==1 GOTO :LOOP

@ECHO Finished!
```

The ping is a (hackish) delay. The `-n` argument effectively becomes how many seconds to delay.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. I'll do a couple of tests and get back to you.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks again. If Autodesk get back to me with a specific switch I'll update